# Retrieve Account Preferences via SSJS or AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap, ssjs

Is it possible to retrieve the available business unit Preferences within Preference Management via ssjs or ampscript?  I am interested in finding the available preferences and corresponding properties of each Preference (i.e. isHidden, isNullable).  I am working on a landing page.

I was able to get what I'm after via SOAP, but I'd rather not use this method on a landing page...

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1">
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="SecurityToken-884da619-59bb-4db6-834d-138322342442">
            <wsse:Username>******</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">******</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <DescribeRequests>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
               <ObjectType>Subscriber</ObjectType>
            </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
         </DescribeRequests>
      </DefinitionRequestMsg>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**Portion of SOAP Response:**

```
            <ExtendedProperties>
                   <ExtendedProperty>
                  <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <ID>14104</ID>
                  <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                  <Name>Preference Name</Name>
                  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
                  <PropertyType>boolean</PropertyType>
                  <IsAccountProperty>false</IsAccountProperty>
                  <Label>a</Label>
                  <Description>Preference Description Is Returned Here</Description>
                  <DefaultValue>True</DefaultValue>
                  <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
                  <IsViewable>true</IsViewable>
                  <IsEditable>true</IsEditable>
                  <IsRestrictedPicklist>false</IsRestrictedPicklist>
                  <IsSendTime>false</IsSendTime>
                  <DisplayOrder>8</DisplayOrder>
               </ExtendedProperty>
            </ExtendedProperties>
```

Comment: Is this E2.0 or E1.0, or something else?

Comment: Hi Kelly. The account is a Core account.  Also, if it's helpful...when I retrieve the BUs via soap, the Account Type is "Connect" with an Edition of "2".

Comment: Something is amiss here.  Business units are an Enterprise 2.0 feature, not available in Core accounts.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said when I retrieve the Account object via soap api (which would return business units if this were an E2.0 account), I am able to see the account information.  I don't believe anything is off about the account.